# Как отредактировать предложение?

Tags: грамматика, стилистика

Текст такой:

Теперь я поспешила в притвор – он был пристроен позже, спустя почти сто лет, в середине XIV века, но именно он хранил многие портреты великой династии.  *Сюда я рвалась, чтобы поближе рассмотреть **тех людей, во власти которых было не только создать и удержать легендарное королевство, но тех, благодаря которым** художники смогли невидимое (духовное) сделать видимым.*

Смысл понятен, но грамматическая форма кажется некорректной из-за двойного союза ***не только...но***, который вроде бы стоит не на месте. Но его перестановка смысл затемняет.

Вроде бы несложное предложение, но отредактировать его близко к авторскому тексту не получается.

А какой вариант редакции предложили бы вы? Нужно ли его редактировать?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Дорогие друзья! **Всем большое-большое спасибо** за ответы, за участие  и за помощь. У меня был вариант правки (целый час сочиняла), но там два предложения, да еще новый текст  добавлен. Я думала, что **можно обойтись без всего этого.**

Вот мой вариант:

Сюда я рвалась, чтобы поближе рассмотреть тех людей, во власти которых было не только создать и удержать легендарное королевство.  Они построили и тот особый мир, в котором жили  и творили художники, сумевшие  невидимое сделать видимым.

Comment: А если "но тех" заменить на "и", авторский смысл сохранится? (Меня интересует именно смысл, поскольку я не смог его понять.) Тире в конце мне не кажется уместным. Может так: "...смогли сделать то самое невидимое — видимым"?

Comment: Грамматически для исправления достаточно (помимо тире) убрать "не только... но": этим союзом нельзя соединить столь разнородные конструкции. Останется двукрактное "тех", которое сохранит желаемое автором усиление.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вы можете записать ваши варианты в ответах, чтобы я видела отредактированное предложение, а то в пересказе сложно понять. А смысл такой: автор говорит о том, что сербские правители  не только создали сильное государство, но и очень много внимания уделяли духовной жизни: строили храмы, приглашали византийских художников для их росписи, также в те времена была создана своя художественная оригинальная школа фресковой живописи. Так что речь идет об одних и тех же людях.  А в конце такой смысл. В церкви  изображены картины Священной истории, которые  в своих деталях очень реалистичны.

Comment: Ваш вариант хорош. Но в первом предложении требуется следующее: *не только создать и удержать, а и **что-то ещё сделать***. Отсутствие инфинитива корректным назвать нельзя. Другое дело, что читатель может это не заметить за счёт плавного перехода.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Я думаю, что в первом предложении можно использовать только первую часть союза (это просто отрицание НЕ ТОЛЬКО).  А раскрытие второй его части может быть описательным и содержаться даже не в одном, а в нескольких предложениях.

Comment: Просто второе предложение с властью уже не согласуется. Но можно: *а и построить тот особый мир...* Таким же образом можно оторваться от сопоставления, если выделить последний фрагмент в новое предложение: *Благодаря им художники смогли невидимое сделать видимым.* Или через тире (переломная конструкция, по Розенталю). Ещё немного странным является сочетание *особый мир*. Тут слишком всё преувеличено: благоприятные условия превращаются в какой-то новый мир. Звучит так, будто в реальном мире художники уже не находятся.

Answer (score 3):

Предложение корявое, потому что непонятно, одна или две группы людей. Если не хочется разбивать его на несколько удобоваримых, то предлагаю такие варианты.

Если одна:

> Сюда я рвалась, чтобы поближе рассмотреть тех людей, которые *не только создали* и удержали легендарное королевство, *но и покровительствовали* художникам, сделавшим самое невидимое – видимым.

Если две:

> Сюда я рвалась, чтобы поближе рассмотреть *не только тех людей*, во
>   власти которых было не только создать и удержать легендарное
>   королевство, *но и тех, благодаря которым* художники смогли то самое
>   невидимое сделать – видимым.

Comment: "Во власти которых" - это значит "которые смогли", речь идет не о реальной власти. Получится; которые смогли дать возможность. То есть тавтология.

Comment: Вопрос-то о союзах. Подставьте те глаголы, которые вам нравятся.

Comment: Предложенная грамматическая схема  верна, но она не может выразить нужный смысл.

Comment: Но мне-то смысл неизвестен. Тут уже к автору оригинала нужно обращаться.

Comment: У меня с автором телепатическая связь, а смысл я объяснила.

Comment: Мой первый вариант описывает правителей, которые сделали два дела: создали королевство и поддержали художников.

Comment: @Sharon Вот, кстати, если заменить это громоздкое "во власти которых было создать.." на простое "которые смогли создать.." или "которым удалось создать..", уже стало бы проще воспринимать текст.

Comment: Sharon, но ведь здесь описываются два типа людей. Об этом свидельствует союз "не только... но и. Мне нравится второй вариант homocomputeris.  Но с единственной правкой: во власти которых было(не только)создать и удержать ... но и. Первую часть союза в скобках опускаем.

Answer (score 2):

> Смысл понятен

Да вот не очень... Приходится догадываться за автора.

> Сюда я рвалась, чтобы поближе рассмотреть *не столько* людей, во
>   власти которых было создать и удержать легендарное королевство,
>   *сколько* тех, благодаря которым художники смогли невидимое (духовное) сделать видимым.

Автор такой смысл пытается передать? Я исхожу из того, что это одни и те же люди, но "рвущаяся Я" больше ценит в них "поддержку художников", нежели талант управления государством.

**Эпилог**

После уточнения смысла исходного текста стало ясно, что вариант не годится.

Comment: Суд по тексту: она хотела увидеть в этих людях не только правителей, но и меценатов, покровителей художников. А у Вас получает не столько, сколько; у нее же не только, но и .

Comment: @Sharon: А вы не можете уточнить у автора, что она **точно** имела в виду? Потому что по тексту, который, увы, корявый, судить достаточно трудно. У  нее ведь не "не только, но и", а "не только, но"...

Comment: @Sharon То есть, принципиальный вопрос (уже упоминавшийся) - это одни и те же люди или разные? Которые королевство создавали и удерживали, и которые давали художникам возможность "выражать невидимое"... Возможно, это ясно из полного текста, но у нас его нет.

Comment: Автор - искусствовед, изучает средневековую церковную живопись. Параллельно знакомится с историей. Представьте: вы много прочитали о правителе государства, узнали его как политика. Но вы знаете его и как человека, который очень много сделал для искусства.  И вот видите его портрет. Ищете в нем черты и политика, и мецената.  Вряд ли автор мне что-либо еще добавит.

Comment: @Sharon "Вряд ли автор мне что-либо еще добавит" - а больше, наверное,  и не надо, этого я и добивался :) Хотя... дополнительная сложность в том, что у автора не "человек", а "люди", и это множественное число вносит оттенок двусмысленности. Скажем, в притворе 10 портретов. Из них пять правителей прославились "удержанием королевства", а другие пять - меценатством. Это одна ситуация. А вторая - *все* эти правители известны и как выдающиеся политики, и как меценаты...

Comment: Да, они все такие.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала заметим что предложение полностью корректное просто двусмысленное (если двусмысленность не криминал, то можно и не редактировать). Двусмысленность связана с тем, что **вторые те** могут отличаться от **первых те**.

Вариант с союзом **но и** и с отдельным от него **не только** (без вторых тех):

> Сюда я рвалась, чтобы поближе рассмотреть тех людей, во власти которых
>   было не только создать и удержать легендарное королевство, но и
>   благодаря которым художники смогли невидимое (духовное) сделать
>   видимым.

Вариант с уточнением при вторых тех:

> Сюда я рвалась, чтобы поближе рассмотреть тех людей, во власти которых
>   было не только создать и удержать легендарное королевство, а при этом тех
>   благодаря которым художники смогли невидимое (духовное) сделать
>   видимым.

В общем эти варианты не сильно лучше/хуже простого предложенного alex_ader:

> Сюда я рвалась, чтобы поближе рассмотреть тех людей, во власти которых
>   было создать и удержать легендарное королевство, тех
>   благодаря которым художники смогли невидимое (духовное) сделать
>   видимым.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В третьем варианте идет простое перечисление, но нет сопоставления: не только...но и. Это важно. Обычно на династических портретах мы видим именно правителей, а в данном случае - не только их.

Answer (score 0):

Улучшенный вариант (порядок слов не супер, но зато грамматика правильная):
*Сюда я рвалась, чтобы поближе рассмотреть тех людей, не только во власти которых было создать и удержать легендарное королевство, но и благодаря которым художники смогли невидимое сделать видимым.*

Своеобразный вариант (с сохранением повтора "тех"):
*Сюда я рвалась, чтобы поближе рассмотреть не лишь тех людей, во власти которых было создать и удержать легендарное королевство, но и тех, благодаря которым художники смогли невидимое сделать видимым.*

Видоизменённый вариант:
*Сюда я рвалась, чтобы поближе рассмотреть тех людей, во власти которых было не только создать и удержать легендарное королевство, но и вдохновить художников на то, чтобы [они смогли] невидимое сделать видимым.*

Comment: Улучшенный? Грамматика стала еще неправильнее, а смысл (и так туманный) еще непонятнее

Comment: Чего неправильнее? Противопоставление стало корректным. Для этого нужно отрицать первую конструкцию.

Answer (score 0):

тех людей, что не только были властны создать и удержать легендарное королевство, а  (но) ещё и позволили (дали, помогли) художникам невидимое (духовное) сделать видимым.